# Getting data from 127.0.0.1 Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on an application using Ionic, Angular, NodeJS and Express.

I need to retrieve data from an application running on my laptop for example at: http://127.0.0.1:20000/data

Currently, I've successfully made it work by using proxy in my local development environment but I would like to know how to approach a situation like this after deploying it to heroku?

I don't know if I'm missing any information, if yes, please let me know, i'll provide it right away.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on http://127.0.0.1:20000/data (Considering it express.js app). You can deploy your angular application by creating prod build. 
Follow steps:

1. Create prod build of angular application
2. Move that build to public folder located under your express application
3. Locate your app.js/index.js and check for following statements, If there are some other lines then update those with following code,

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Now start your express.js application and open your url into browser.